# Better Flex memory profiling tools

Tags: apache-flex, memory-leaks, adobe, profiler

Does anyone know of any better tools that the Flex Builder Profiler? I've googled and googled to no avail.

While the FB tools are OK for small apps / small leak situations, they're nowhere near adequate for wading through the thicket of object references that can arise in a large scale Flex app (that is leaking memory heavily). In particular, any reasonably complex view structure ends up with huge numbers of parent/child object references to the top level view - none of which are at all relevant to finding the one or two refs from *outside* the parent child subgraph that are causing the whole bolus to be non-GC'able.

If no one has any better suggestions, I'm seriously considering writing a tool to parse the saved profile dumps that Flex Builder can generate so that I can do my own "graph pruning" to find the important refs. If I go this route, collaboration would be welcome!

Comment: Wow. Almost a whole month and no one has any suggestions? This must truly be a problem! Anyone? Please!

Comment: I've also thought about writing a tool to parse the profiles. Would be very useful. Problem is; is there a specification for the format?

Answer (score 1):

I like your DIY attitude.  I couldn't find any Profiler alternatives either, but [here's an article](http://www.insideria.com/2008/06/profiling-flex-applications-sa.html) that helped me a lot by one of the authors of the Adobe **Training from the Source** book.  I'd suggest doing spot reviews on the coding suggestions outlined here.  HTH.

UPDATE: [De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/downloads) also has a memory monitor feature.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/pushbuttonengine/source/browse/trunk/src/com/pblabs/engine/debug/Profiler.as

Very interesting project for Flex applications.

Comment: Nice.  How would one incorporate just that piece in a project?

Answer (score 0):

Powerflasher's FDT IDE has an elaborate profiling tool.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3151

Good things are happening :)